# How best to resign from a company after only a little over a month and paid training

Tags: professionalism, communication, resignation

I was wondering if there is a good way to go about this.  I just recently walked into some inheritance that I wasn't expecting and have the option of going back to school full time for a year that would allow me to complete my education.

It all seems a very unfortunate set of circumstances as I left my last job for lack of opportunities.  The new place is fine, but are assigning me responsibilities that weren't included in the answer for my "what would my responsibilities be if I worked there?" question when I was interviewing.  They have, however, recently sent me to a couple of certificate courses that they paid me for.

Really though, finishing school (mechanical engineering) this year would offer me other job opportunities (and more money) that I originally wouldn't have been able to get for several more years after completing night school.

Any suggestions how I can do this?  Of course I will be honest, just hoped there might be a few people who have either experienced this before or have some suggestions.

Comment: This is something employers do have to deal with from time to time. It's almost exactly the example my company uses when discussing "bus factor" -- we didn't like thinking about being hit by a bus, so we instead explained a scenario wherein the employee wins the lottery and quits unexpectedly.

Comment: Is there any possibility of staying on while you finish your education?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I say when resigning after just a month?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/what-do-i-say-when-resigning-after-just-a-month)

Comment: My company has been flexible with promising new hires that had a few classes left. Perhaps they will work with you.

Answer (score 6):

Simply write a brief resignation letter stating that you need to leave on relatively short notice due to "unforeseen personal reasons." While most employers will want to ask, the majority would consider it poor form to do so or would expect you to simply not tell them the reason why.

It may not be advisable to tell a co-worker the true reasons for your leaving as unless they are exceptionally close friends, they will relay the reason to people in the company after you leave. This may sour future attempts to obtain employment, especially in a small industry.