# how to resign gratefully

Tags: job-change

I have been working in a new company for only 1 month and I have received another better offer. How should I resign gratefully with the current employer? Will they accept if I tell them that I get a better offer? Or should I tell them that I don't think I fit for this position?

Comment: Possible Duplicates [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149) and [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/) to name a couple. The latter is what I'm marking as a duplicate.

Comment: did you mean "gracefully" ?

Answer (score 2):

Be frank and honest; say it's a money thing, shake their hand, ask for a reference and leave
 :)