# transfer to another company

Tags: resignation

I am a fresh graduate and Im a 1 month old employee now. But I want to transfer to another company... is it risky to accept the job for that company even though you've just filed a resignation letter on your current company?

Comment: Why would it be risky? As long as you stay to your notice period, I think there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you plan so that the new start date is after the last day of work in the old company. Check your contract to see how long notice period you have.

You should be aware that if you often quit jobs after a short period (I'd say less than 6 months) it will not look good on your resume. Here are some questions that deal with that issue: [1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6393/105), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17119/105)

If it's happening once, it's not a big deal especially if you can explain why, but a recurring pattern will make you seem like a jobhopper that managers will be more reluctant to hire.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's typical to resign only **after** you've accepted another offer (as to not find yourself unemployed).

Just make sure you mention the required notice period (as likely stipulated in your contract) to the new employer - most of the time, they'd happily allow you to only start after your notice period with your current employer is up (assuming it isn't unreasonably long).