# Accepting a management position after initially being turned down

Tags: job-offer, new-hires, position

Last year I started working as the graphic and web designer of a call center. After several months, my boss opened a marketing agency where I was the first guy working there for 7 months. I'm a graphic and print designer with strong knowledge in web design and the new agency didn't need anyone else at the time when it was a startup.

After some months, they hired 2 other employees: one developer and another graphic designer. I managed the team to the best of my ability, and was promised the manager position at the end of the next month.

The developer was not really experienced and the only reason they hired that guy was because he was the only one who wanted to work there for that price. On ALL of our projects I had to help him just to get my own work done.

One day my employer informed me that the new manager will be the developer even though they promised me the position. The reason given for the decision was because of his work performance, a reason I highly doubt.

The situation quickly deteriorated after that and I told my employer I will quit at the end of the month. I found a new job 2 weeks after, but 2 days ago I got a call from one of my bosses that they fired the developer/manager and are now offering the management position to me with double the pay. I'm hesitant to accept this offer to work there again. I'm happy with my new job but they offered me an attractive salary.

**How can I evaluate this offer after initially being declined?**

Comment: Welcome to the site PJ. We can't make up your mind for you so these kinds of personal [advice questions are off-topic here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/#2695). Resigning a new job is also a common topic which is covered extensively [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully) and [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6393/what-do-i-say-when-resigning-after-just-a-month). General consensus: **don't**. You can get away with it once but it can be career suicide.

Comment: @PJ - I have AGGRESSIVELY edited your question to better reflect what I think you are trying to ask. If I am wrong, please re - edit.

Comment: Welcome to the world of office politics.  Manager is the breaking line between merit promotions and political promotions in most companies.  If you take the position, you have to learn how to play in "both" arenas.

Comment: @Lilienthal It looks like your off-topic link is broken.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the quick heads-up, edited it just within the limit and all 3 links should now work. (Turns out you can't shorten meta links from /question/ to /q/.)

Comment: @Anthony thanks a lot, I was writing this from my phone and got too much into detail

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure your edit has the core question right since, as I understand it, the OP has either already started his new job or accepted the offer which is an important part of the dynamic here. @ OP: Consider updating your post with a clearer time-line for your final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your reluctance. Obviously this company needs you. So you need to balance the extra income against the fact that they don't seem trustworthy. My first response in such a situation would be to ask for a lot more than double and feel out how desperate they are if you already have a satisfactory job. That would make it easier to make a more concrete decision.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what a "loan" means at the end of your question? How are they offering you a loan? I wouldn't take any job where I have to re-pay something unless it had some sort of expiration with employment time.

In any event, I can assure you this is a horrible idea to take up their offer. If I am understanding things correctly, it sounds like a fairly hostile environment and now they're trying to take you back after losing one (or two from what I can gather) individual on the team. So you're returning by yourself but with promise of double pay, which no doubt looks attractive until you worked there for a few more years with no pay increase and whatever "loan" they offered you is still in effect.

At the end of it, you'll lose two jobs. The one you just had, and the one you're going back to.

Also take into account it wasn't your boss who called you and offered you the job. It was one of your employees. So I wouldn't jump ships just yet until you get a call from your boss.

Comment: sorry, It was actually my boss who called me and loan was meant to be salary, thanks for the tip!