# How can I turn another offer into a raise, after only working at a company for a few months?

Tags: management, negotiation, job-offer, company-culture

I work at a start-up directly under the founder who is difficult to work for. There's been a lot of turnover in my position, and industry peers speak poorly of him and avoid doing business with him due to his abrasiveness.

I'm passionate about the work we do, but the long hours (I often work 6 days a week) and demoralizing company culture is negatively impacting my quality of life.

I've only been at the company for a few months, but I've just received a job offer from an established organization for more money. I'm not passionate about the work they do, but my specific job duties would be more fulfilling and there would be room for growth.

I'm considering going with the offer, but I'm wondering if I should discuss it with my current boss to see if I can a) Get him to change his negative behavior b) Get a raise c) negotiate for more fulfilling job duties.

It's a small company and I know he wouldn't want to lose me, however I'm afraid using the second job offer as leverage could backfire in the future. What if he agrees to make the necessary changes,but then goes back on his end of the deal after I turn down the other company?

Comment: Welcome to [workplace.se] BB! Have you taken a look at [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4224) which seems to ask the same thing and has a lot of answers on it? If your question is different somehow, or the answers aren't of value, could you explain why, and then we can help [edit] your post to get you some useful answers!

Comment: If you want quality of life, may as well take the new job.  So what if you make more money but still work 6 day weeks? Why would your morale improve merely by having more money?

Comment: Could you clarify if you are looking for techniques to [get a raise to match a job offer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/get-a-raise-to-match-another-job-offer) or for help deciding what to do?

Comment: @MeredithPoor It's not the more money that would improve my moral, but the leaving of a negative boss, for one who seems to have better interpersonal skills.

Comment: @jcmeloni I don't know if it's appropriate for me to bring up the issues and the ultimatum to my current boss, since I've only worked with him for 3 months, or if I should just leave.

Comment: @BBWilliams Thanks for the clarification. Because the title and body of your question mismatch, I couldn't tell if this was a duplicate question, an unanswerable question, or something we could help figure out.

Answer (score 4):

So you are passionate about the work, but the reality of the boss, the hours and culture are making you contemplate a move after only a few months, well I know what I'd do...

Studys have shown (think it was on hbr, I'll update if I can find it), that all this follow your passion thing is just good for making you lose you passion.

By the sound of things using the offer as a negotiating point in your current role won't work, I'd generally advise against a strategy like this anyway, it never really works out.

Sounds like the growth opportunities are where I would head, even if they weren't ideal, the other situation sounds like a downward spiral, even if I ended up getting more money to stay.

Just my 2 cents, know "should I quit" advice isn't popular here.

Comment: Even if an offer for more money ( at his current job ) is extended he will always be "that guy who asked for more money after only 3 months" and its safe to say you WOULD NOT get a pay raise for awhile ( considering the author works under the founder ). In the end while his job duties might changed and he could bargin a higher salary the attitude of the boss is one thing that likely won't change if an offer is extended. He might even tell you what he thinks of your actions ( i.e. tell you to leave that day ) and you would find yourself on the negative side of somebody who could be an asset.

Comment: I've been in a similar passion situation, and I think it's just Stockholm syndrome

Comment: thanks @MarkChapman please do update if you find the article

Comment: @Ramhound You're both probably right, his behavior is unlikely to change

Comment: @KFranklin - Just remember that while he might me jerk today you might find yourself needing his help in 10 dears or he might be the next Bill Gates ( doubtful considering he has had so many people leave under him ).  The important part is to leave on the right note, don't worry about leaving him in bad situation ( one he created himself ), leave knowing you personally did everything to make the transition easier.