# Staying in company after they offer higher pay than my new job

Tags: salary, new-job

I am currently working in a company which paid only 4% hike. I asked them for more and they clearly said that its not possible, not even 1 % more. So I decided to search for a new job and got one with 25% hike. I accepted the offer and now I'am in my notice period.

My current employer now offers same 25% since I told them hike is the only reason for my leave. They are forcing me to accept their offer with same hike.

I am confused here. After accepting the offer with the current employer

1. will I be treated fair and square?
2. will they put on some legal agreement to lock me with current employer for years?
3. is it advisable to accept current employer's offer? If not, how can I refuse it ?

Comment: Take the new job.  If the employer keeps finding their talent bailing out for more pay, they'll fix their compensation across the board. They won't do that until it's putting their business at risk.

Comment: This question is asking us which job you should take which is off topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You accepted the offer with the new company. That is the only thing that you need to tell them.

Unless there is some other obligation you have: must work for X years after tuition or training or owe them the cost of the benefit; accepting moving expenses and need to pay it back if you leave within X years; they can't really stop you.

Many questions on this site ask about trying to determine if you should stay with the old company. Many times people find out that the promised benefit by the old company never materializes, or they are never trusted by the old company again. Accepting the increased offer by the old company frequently just delays the time frame of the move to another company.

Sit though the meeting with the managers, be polite; and then thank them for the offer, but tell them you have made a commitment to join the new company.

Finish the notice period, and enjoy your new job.

Comment: I think , i shouldnt have disclosed my new offer hike to the current employer!!! Thanks for answer @mhoran

Comment: And remember if you accept that one big hike from them, you will probably not get another pay raise for years.

Answer (score 6):

"forcing" you? You already quit, all they can do is force you not to work through your notice period.

The answer is they feel they have to meet the higher rate, but it's a lose-lose situation for both of you. Other coworkers will see how to get rises, and you have very little goodwill for management, nor, I am betting, them for you. [There are other questions on this topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/get-a-raise-to-match-another-job-offer/6420#6420)

I think you should accept the new offer, and just work through the notice period you've already given. There's no need to be rude, just say that you've committed to the new job and have already begun the quitting process in your current job. Reversing that would be unfair to everyone.

Comment: I had a discussion with my manager and after my refusal , a meeting was planned between my manager's manager and me this week..all they try convince me is "its same hike , what problem do you have" ., i wondering how to justify my refusal in right words

Comment: You don't need to justify your refusal. It's up to you who you work for. However you might suggest to them that not long ago they said "it's impossible to give you more than a 4% raise", and now that turns out not to be true. But do that very, very carefully and politely.

Comment: You might even mention the bad situation they've set up, even just by asking "what happens next time I want a pay rise?" But I would stick with "sorry, I'm already committed to my new job".

Answer (score 4):

Leave.

They tell you a further pay hike is not possible but then offer you one 6 times larger as soon as they are faced with you leaving.  This means you are worth the original pay hike you requested and that they can afford it but didn't want to give you it for reasons unknown.
 This is not the kind of place you want to work if you need to threaten to leave in order to be paid what you are worth to them.

How much more will they secretly deny you?