# Tips for salary negotiation

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

I'm currently working as a Senior Software Developer I at a big company. I have been working here for 2.5 years and my current salary is 53k/year.

I realized that I have more qualifications, and I actually know more stuff than my colleague which am almost certain are paid way above me.

I get head hunted daily for similar positions where the salary is between 75k - 85k, and If I go to apply I'm fairly certain I would end up with an offer to one of them.

I'm the worst to anything related to negotiation. What would be the best way for me to go to my manager and ask for a title (Sr Dev II) and pay raise ? 
Do I just as my manager for a 1vs1 meeting and ask him point blank? Or is it better if I get an offer somewhere else and use it to negotiate my raise?

Comment: Also relevant - [Do I mention a competing offer when negotiating a raise?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33457/do-i-mention-a-competing-offer-when-negotiating-a-raise)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere never been promoted and no raise. 6 or 7 months ago my manager did told me I was doing good job and told me I was the most Senior in the team (in term of the one that knows the most technical stuff)

Comment: Also also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary

Answer (score 6):

> What would be the best way for me to my manager and ask for a title
>   (Sr Dev II) and pay raise ?

You are going to have to get over this discomfort and *learn to ask for what you want*.  You need to do this professionally, in a one on one meeting you set up with your manager.

I would suggest that you have data to backup your request from the many sources of this information that are available via Google.  This article has some excellent steps to help.  [How to ask for what you want.](https://www.forbes.com/sites/margiewarrell/2013/04/24/7-keys-to-asking-for-what-you-really-want-so-you-get-it/#51c97ee51a56)

Salary surveys are **one** part of this negotiation, but also *be prepared to demonstrate your value to your company*.  Do this by reviewing your contributions to the company, and if you can how they either helped make or save the company money.

And finally, if the salary discrepancy between what your worth and where you are currently is great enough, *and in your case it might be*, be prepared to begin looking for another job.  Sometimes in my experience its the only way to make up the difference if you work for a short sighted employer.

> Or is it better if I get an offer somewhere else and use it to
>   negotiate my raise?

This tactic may work in the short term, but the reality is you essentially forced your way ( *threatening to take another offer* ) into a raise.  This *may* work once, but this will definitely leave a bad impression with your current employer.  If you cannot get the appropriate salary by asking ( *assuming the facts you presented are correct* ), then just leave.

Comment: @Paulus2 I worked at a company once where my salary was a bit low, and he was a bit of a micromanager.  I got another offer, and too my surprise he was very upset that I wanted to leave and asked what he could do to make me stay.  I believed him, and we worked out the details and I stayed.  *But* in hind sight that was a very risky move on my part.  They could have kept me there long enough to find a replacement and then kicked me to the curb.

Comment: For nearly ten years I provided my management with a chart showing the net value I brought to the organisation (revenue and sales minus costs and expenses). The line was high, and continued to go up at an ever steepening gradient. It made for quite sensible discussions :-)