# How to ask for more money in current job when another company is offereing substantially more?

Tags: salary, new-job

I'm currently working in a small company and I really enjoy the work I'm doing and the people I work with, as well as with the boss himself, with whom I work closely. I do good work and my boss is happy with my performance.

I was recently approached by a recruiter enquiring if I'd be intersted in considering a position at another company. I wasn't really interested in leaving my current position, but I agreed to an interview out of curiosity. The new company is much bigger and appears to be more stuffy than my current position, so considering I don't want to move, I'll probably turn it down. However, the new company is offering substantially more than I'm making in my current position. I would consider leaving just for that.

My question is, considering I don't want to move is there a good way to approach this with my boss? I'd like him to know that the market is offering a lot more than what he is but I don't want to leave. How can I approach my boss to ask for more money showing how much I would like to be paid? I don't want to taint the relationship with my boss because 1) he's my boss and that would be bad, and 2) I work so closely with him.

Comment: Hey there @DaveDev , I suggested a possible duplicate/highly related post to the situation you describe here. Please, take a look at it and, in case you think it's not a duplicate or it does not answer your question, explain here why so, and edit the post accordingly to make your different question stand out more... Welcome to The Workplace BTW :)

Comment: Here is another possible duplicate/highly related post: [How do I convince my employer to match the salary of my new job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/123142/73791)