# Two offers same time. How to negotiate and get the best outcome?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-offer, negotiation

Yesterday, I received an offer in hand. And that is from a franchise. The branch is 25 mins away from where I live, and offering $11/hr. The environment seems ok, and the branch is very busy. Everyone there speaks english.

Today, I got a phone call from another branch that I was interviewing with last week too. The other branch is not too busy, actually very slow, and is 10 mins away from where I live. This manager interviewed and spoke with me in my (our) language. Today, he called and said he accepeted me and will send me an offer with $12.5/hr. I said ok I will wait. then he called again, and said "*seems like there is another offer, I can't send this written offer unless you decline that other offer*" - (system thing).

My main purpose is NOT to speak my language and to learn/improve my English, and to learn the industry (busier place). Hence why I prefer current offer.

I have to reply fast. I want to call the current offer ($11/hr, farther, busier) and negotiate based on what I was told from today's alternative ($12.5/hr, closer, slower). How can I, without having BOTH offers in hand, get the best out of these two offer professionally and without losing both?

Note: Asking this on behalf of a relative.

**EDIT regarding the duplicate flag:**
The duplicate is not a duplicate, as I **do not have** BOTH offers in hand. One is written and one is verbal. and I HAVE to decline the one in hand in hope to get the other.

Comment: There is one question to ask yourself here.  Am I willing to give up the extra 1.5/hr to get the growth benefits of the other branch.  Sometimes its better to sacrifice now for the big payoff later.

Comment: The duplicate is not a duplicate, as I do not have BOTH offers in hand. One is written and one is verbal, and I HAVE to decline the one in hand in hope to gain the other. @DavidK

Comment: Also: [Can I negotiate for a higher salary based on a higher offer I got elsewhere?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70969)

Comment: @Sandra The answers to that question seem to work for your case as well. Do you see anything missing that is not covered by those answers?

Comment: @SandraK If you think this question was unjustly closed, please post in Meta and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: @SandraK You can use a verbal offer in negotiations. Trying to negotiate an offer always carries the risk of losing it (but this should be unlikely, if they're reasonable, and you don't say all the wrong things).

Comment: Your English is pretty good. Better than most, if you ask me. If this place speaks both languages, wouldn't that be helpful? Since you can speak your language for clarification?

Comment: @Dan This issue is no mine (see Note in OP). Their English is not good and could use improvements. I would go for growth instead of the money as IDrinkAndIKnowThings said. But that is just opinion. Thanks