# Can I use a (rejected) offer to negotiate a better salary at my current job?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I recently interviewed at a large tech company and was given a very nice offer; more than 3x what I currently make. The only downside and potential deal-breaker for me is that it would require relocation, which is next to impossible due to a unique personal situation I am in. I ended up turning the offer down a few months ago.

I love working at my current employer and am very excited about the work I do there, so I'm quite content with my current situation. However I can't help wondering if there's a way I could use the offer to my advantage at my current job? If I were to attempt to negotiate a raise, would that be something appropriate to bring up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a raise to match another job offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/get-a-raise-to-match-another-job-offer)

Comment: @Mangocherry I believe this is different enough to be kept open, as in this scenario, the OP has already rejected the other offer.

Answer (score 17):

> I ended up turning the offer down a few months ago.

You are late for negotiations, and don't have anything to walk away to.

> more than 3x what I currently make

That could be due to higher cost of living etc in the new city/country, so fix upon some expected salary first. Is 2x good enough? 30%? anything over x? Is it available in your current location for your experience and work? etc.

> I'm quite content with my current situation.

Any offhanded technique will end up burning bridges, so don't use them here, as it will disturb the balance you want in life (location, contentment).

> If I were to attempt to negotiate a raise, would that be something appropriate to bring up?

Try not to put it across as a negotiation. What happens in the case when employer declines? What happens in case employer thinks you are looking to leave? This could hurt career progression.

*Do not use the word "negotiation".  Use the word "discussion" instead.*

> if there's a way I could use the offer to my advantage at my current job?

Yes. Discuss, not negotiate. You should here want them to bump your offer out of goodwill, not pressure tactics. Avoid hard stances of any kind.

Keep your expectations simple here.  Talk to your manager, and let him know of facts:

Focus on the good things about the job:
1. Contentment
2. Feel motivated
3. Like the work etc

Then, upon:
4. Location
5. Loyalty to the company
6. Feeling undervalued

Finally, check if there is something they could do for you. A good manager will not want to lose the goodwill of a good employee, but everyone has their constraints.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking a hard stance, but the risks increase dramatically and the rational for staying if they meet your demands needs to be solid. "I haven't been promoted in X years, and I feel it is time to move on if I can't be promoted to job Y which I just found internally posted." If you get the new posting, you had better be very happy and grateful, or you will get stuck for another X years.

Comment: I upvoted this answer for pointing out reasons to not use the old offer to negotiate with the current employer. I think it's worth pointing out that raises should be based on value you're providing to your current employer. Comparing to some third party offer isn't relevant, and bringing that other offer into the discussion does nothing but tip your employer off that you're out shopping for a new job.

Comment: Yes, an offer that you rejected isn't a very good bargaining chip. In total, the potential job with 3x the salary was not worth more to you than your current job. Evidently, your current job is already a "better offer" than the one with a bigger salary. Your employer is already paying you enough to keep you around, the fact that you rejected the other offer is actually evidence that they *don't* need to pay you more!

Answer (score 4):

If you attempt to manipulate a current employer with an outstanding offer (your old offer isn't an outstanding offer), you can find yourself unemployed. It isn't uncommon to terminate an employee who tries using an offer to get a raise. For one thing, quite often an employee who's dissatisfied enough to go all the way through the interview process that they get an offer is going to leave sooner than later.

In your case, about the best you can do is explain that you have "researched" the market rate for your services and you believe a raise is in order. There are MANY answers to "How do I asked for a raise?"

Comment: Yeah agreed. An offer is really your failsafe should negotiations fail and your company's rejection is not something you want to accept. You shouldn't bring it up unless you intend to go with that option.

Answer (score 2):

Usually people have a job offer in hand and they go up to their boss and say,

> Hey look, I need a raise to X amount.

The boss will say something like,

> Hey look, we can't give you that. You can try other places but I don't think you will do better.

Then you say,

> Hey look, I actually did. I turn in my two weeks, see you later.

Then the boss will say,

> Hey look, I better notify HR that this dude just turned in his notice and to post a job so we can find his replacement.

If you go to said boss with a rejected offer and try to make him foolish looking, it might work to some degree. He might give you the raise for the time being and appear very glad that you're staying. Reality is that might not be the case always.